# reuters data scraping in R with rvest, find CSS selector

Tags: r, web-scraping, css-selectors, html-parsing, rvest

Yes, I know there are similar questions, I've read the answers and tried those which I could implement. So, sorry in advance in case the question is stupid :)

I'm scraping the age of company board members from Reuters for a list of companies.
Here's the link: http://www.reuters.com/finance/stocks/companyOfficers?symbol=MSFT

I'm using rvest library and selectorgadget to find proper CSS selector.
Here's the code:

```
library(rvest)
d = read_html("http://www.reuters.com/finance/stocks/companyOfficers?symbol=GAZP.RTS")

d %>% html_nodes("#companyNews:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(2)") %>% html_text()
```

The result is

```
character(0)
```

I think I have the wrong CSS selector. Can you please tell me how to select the table?

Comment: _" You may not remove, alter, forward, scrape, copy, sell, distribute, retransmit, create derivative works or otherwise make available the Content to third parties without our prior written consent,"_ It's unlikely you're doing this for your own edification unless you can provide documentation otherwise.

Comment: I'm doing this for my thesis (board experience ~ company performance). So, I will not _make available the Content to third parties_. Still, thank you for this point. I'll ask them if I can use aggregated data for this purpose. I also believe that I can use this data for myself since my organization have the subscription for their services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `html_session` to get the data loaded properly:

```
library(rvest)

url <- 'http://www.reuters.com/finance/stocks/companyOfficers?symbol=MSFT.O'
site <- html_session(url) %>% read_html()

site %>% html_node('#companyNews:first-child table') %>% html_table()

##                     Name Age Since                                  Current Position
## 1          John Thompson  66  2014                 Independent Chairman of the Board
## 2         Bradford Smith  57  2015                    President, Chief Legal Officer
## 3          Satya Nadella  48  2014                 Chief Executive Officer, Director
## 4          William Gates  60  2014          Founder and Technology Advisor, Director
## 5               Amy Hood  43  2013 Chief Financial Officer, Executive Vice President
## 6  Christopher Capossela  45  2014 Executive Vice President, Chief Marketing Officer
## 7         Kathleen Hogan  49  2014        Executive Vice President - Human Resources
## 8       Margaret Johnson  54  2014   Executive Vice President - Business Development
## 9           Ifeanyi Amah  NA  2016                          Chief Technology Officer
## 10         Keith Lorizio  NA  2016              Vice President - North America Sales
## 11       Teri List-Stoll  53  2014                              Independent Director
## 12       G. Mason Morfit  40  2014                              Independent Director
## 13         Charles Noski  63  2003                              Independent Director
## 14          Helmut Panke  69  2003                              Independent Director
## 15        Charles Scharf  50  2014                              Independent Director
## 16          John Stanton  60  2014                              Independent Director
## 17             Chris Suh  NA    NA              General Manager - Investor Relations
```

Comment: Thank you very much! How did you realise that the CSS selector should be `#companyNews:first-child table`?

Comment: selectorgadget makes decent guesses, but rarely returns the optimal selector, so I looked at the HTML and tried a few options. The tables don't have unique IDs, so the selector has to be relative, and there are two tables in `div#companyNews`, so I used `:first-child` to subset. `rvest` links to [a short, fun tutorial](http://flukeout.github.io/) that teaches you pretty much everything you need to know.